# How do I prevent a RESTful service from XSS attacks

Tags: validation, rest, encoding, xss

Of course, I know that the script code is executed on client side. But what countermeasures should be introduced at service-side in order to provide a maximum of security concerning XSS.
Is output encoding reasonable, or are there any other countermeasures that should be applied?

**[EDIT]**

If I send back the content as HTML encoded, all existing XML schema files and the bean validation will be inoperative since the XSD schema as well the bean validation are using the same regular expression.

```
<xs:simpleType name="addressNumber">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1}[0-9a-z/\\ -]{0,7}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem better and why the "same-origin policy" or CORS isn't enough?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need to secure a RESTful service against the most common attacks. Therefore I refere to the OWASP `REST Security Cheat Sheet`. Since the CSRF is a listed threat there which can arise out of an XSS flaw, I need to prent XSS from happening first. I know how I prevent XSS in a JSF application. Encoding the data into HTML style is simply enough. But for a REST service I'm not sure about how to do this. So far I know about two possibilities. (Next comment)

Comment: **1)** Perform a input validation, and reject any mailicious content (Not always possible) 
**2)** Encode all the response data. But this will violate all my existing validation (Bean validation and XML schema validation) although the data is valid. The term `<script>` in an encoded style will look like: `&#x3C;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3E;` Further this isn't a good approch, since also other web services may retrieve that data. But they prefer the data un- encoded. I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42093/29820) on IT - Security! The most important things are:

- Use a standart XML parser library that encodes characters like < and >
- Check that the `content-type` header is set to `application/xml`
- Add additional `X-Content-Type-Options` header and set the value to `nosniff`
- Perform service side input validation (White listing is the most reliable approach)

Comment: +1 for "Perform service side input validation". Here is what could happen if we are not doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788845/how-to-protect-the-frontend-from-xss-caused-by-data-from-a-rest-api/77215725#77215725